# How to add email under author in pandoc markdown to pdf?

Tags: yaml, latex, pandoc

I can't figure out how to add an email address on the title page under the author name on the title page. Seems like a basic thing?

My YAML looks like this:

```
---
title: My title
subtitle: My subtitle
date: \today

author: My Name
email: my.name@email.com

---
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the default pandoc template for LaTeX is used for the conversion,
this worked for me:

```yaml
---
title: My title
subtitle: My subtitle
date: \today

author: |
  | My Name
  | my.name@email.com
---
```